# Disable keyboard accent merging

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have no idea how this behavior is called.

Let's say I type this char - `'`. Now instead of it being just a char, it's a modifier. If I press `'`, `a`it turns into `à`. Or if I press `'` `Space` then instead of `'`  I get `'` since the space is being used to turn off the modification status.

How do I turn off that behavior?

I'm using the US international keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of US international PC.  It is designed to do what you describe.  Instead use US or ABC.