# Disable diacritics auto insertion like á and é on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, internationalization

I need to work on an old iMac sporting High Sierra for some time.

The problem I have is that pressing the keys `'` then `e` outputs `é`, when I would like it to simply print `'e`. Same for `'` then `a`.

I am mostly programming on this machine and do not need this behaviour.

My keyboard has a US QWERTY Tenkeyless Windows layout. The system's language is set to be `English (U.S.)`, the input source is `U.S. International - PC`. This machine has a different user using a French AZERTY Apple keyboard layout with different localisation settings and I don't want any change to affect them.

I use the Compose key on Ubuntu and WinCompose on Windows to insert diacritics *when I need them*. Replicating this behaviour on this machine is not a requirement, but I would like my typing experience while programming to be the same.

What can I do to avoid this change when typing?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439009/disable-keyboard-accent-merging/439013#439013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the "International PC" labelled layout unless you want an emulation of Microsoft behaviour for your 'dead keys' [which Microsoft doesn't actually have].

US International PC has unusual [for Mac] dead keys that emulate Windows International behaviour by not actually being 'dead' but permanently 'live'.

[image]

The two keys marked in orange will activate their 'dead key' equivalent of becoming accent keys rather than actual characters, unless you follow them with Space or punctuation - just like Windows International does.

The Mac's normal behaviour is to only activate these special use accents if intentionally invoked by pressing Opt [Alt] plus the dead key, followed by the letter you wish to add an accent to.

If you switch to the regular US keyboard, then plain keys are 'just keys'

[image]

and only when you hold Opt do you get the dead key accents [& there are more of them]

[image]

Whether the keyboard has a ten-key or not doesn't affect this behaviour.

Comment: My hero! I guess I was lead astray by the fact French keyboard layouts differ between Windows and Mac, so when I saw `PC` I thought I was selecting a subtle keyboard layout variant. Thanks