# The character '"'and 'i' replaces to ï automatically, and it messes with my code, how can I disable this?

Tags: macos

The character '"'and 'i' replaces to 'ï' automatically, and it messes with my code, how can I disable this?

Comment: What version of macOS - what Text Input - in keyboard settings are you using?

Comment: Answered a few times before, like here:   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444549/disable-diacritics-auto-insertion-like-á-and-é-on-macos/444550#444550

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. In System settings -> Keyboard -> Text input: change from US - international to US, and voila, problem solved.