# Why do I keep getting á when I press ' than press a?

Tags: macos, keyboard

On my macbook if I want to write single quotation `'` then letter `a` I get letter `á` instead of `'a` what is the problem, and how can I fix it? 
Example: if I want to write apple inside single quotation like `'apple'` I get `ápple`

Comment: You're using the wrong character for single quotation marks. Quotation marks (double and single) share the same key on a standard ANSI/ISO keyboard layout, just press shift for double quotation marks, and no modifier key for single quotation marks. If you're interested in the differences, google the backtick  `'` vs quotation marks `'`.

Comment: @AVelj  No, he is using the right keys but the wrong input source/keyboard layout.   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439009/disable-keyboard-accent-merging/439013#439013

Answer (score 2):

Go to system preferences > keyboard > input sources and get rid of the item called US International PC.  Instead use US or ABC.

(US International PC is a special layout intended for users who want to easily make the most common accented characters in W European languages)

Comment: You solved the problem, thank you very much